# change class of images via onError

Tags: html, class, onerror

When using JavaScript and HTML why wont this work to change the class of an image if it is from a broken url?

`onError="this.style.display=\'none\';this.class=null;"`

i have also tried this:

`onError="this.style.display=\'none\';class=null;"`

and

`onError="this.style.display=\'none\';class='';"`

what could work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `this.className` instead of `this.class` or `class` .

```
<img src="/abc.png" class="random" onError="this.style.display='none';this.className='';" />
```

Comment: Thanks!! That's fixed it. There is no reference that I could find for this kinda specific stuff :( oh well. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the css class the property you are looking for is called `className` not `class`. So you should change that.

```
<img class='test' src="./lad" onError="this.style.display='none'; this.className=''">
```

See this fiddle for comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/awbrpn99/